# A question on algebraically closed field

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, cardinals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field . Consider the commutative ring , with unity , $A=k^\mathbb N=\prod_{i\in \mathbb N}k$ . Consider the proper ideal $I=\oplus_{i\in \mathbb N}k(=k^{(\mathbb N)})$ of $A$ ; let $m$ be a maximal ideal of $A$ containing $I$ .  Then $A/m$ is a field . Is it true that $A/m$ is algebraically closed and is uncountable ?

Comment: Is I not a maximal ideal?

Comment: @Sky : I am not sure . But why does it matter ?

Comment: it is just a question. we can consider $\prod k/\coprod k$,the element $(1,0,1,0,1,0...)+\coprod k$ is not invertible.So the infinite direct sum is not maximal ideal.

Comment: I still want to know what is the maximal ideal in infinite product containing infinite sum?

Comment: Given a non-principal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$, there is a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_{\mathcal{U}}:=\big\{(a_i):\{i:a_i=0\}\in\mathcal{U}\big\}$ containing $I$. Every maximal ideal containing $I$ is of this form.